# how to select minimum salary of manager from employee table

Tags: sql

How do I find the minimum salary of manager from employee table?

Employee Table:

```
(Emp_id,first name,last name,dept_id,manager_id,Salary)
```

Comment: How do you determine what employee is a manager?

Answer (score 0):

If you have managers as rows that do not have a `manager_id` you might want to try something like this:

```
SELECT MIN(`Salary`) FROM `employee` WHERE `manager_id` IS NULL
```

Comment: Employee Table:

(Emp_id,first name,last name,dept_id,manager_id,Salary)

Comment: Yes although surely `manager_id` references the `emp_id` of a manager in this table. Therefore a manager would not have a `manager_id`, and hence the value of `manager_id` for that entry would be set to `NULL` or another suitable value.